# Overlay a live WiFi camera image

Tags: wi-fi, camera, images, overlay

I am using a WiFi endoscope camera with an Acer Android tablet, for woodturning hollow forms. The camera points to a cutter on the same structure as the camera so that the camera is always focussed on the cutter.

I need to be able to superimpose a graphic that I have created over the live image of the cutter. Essentially the image is of the cutter, but with a margin drawn around it.

I have tried many apps that allow overlaying one saved image over another, but none of them work with a live camera "feed". I found one that does allow an image to be superimposed over a live camera feed, but it will only use the camera feed from the camera on the tablet.

Can anyone here help me with this?

Comment: well that looks like a good custom app, it s possible if you are using anything above android 8.0 If you want to see a custom overlay of objects on a live feed camera ,then there is no ready made app on store , however i am working on it and could get it for you on store if you can specify , what are you looking to put and what kind of features would like to have on it?

Comment: Andre: My tablet is running android 6 and acer says that it cannot be updated. To show you what I am trying to do, here is a link to a youtube video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0kYF3fgwhBs If you forward to 7:13, you will see the idea of using a camera to stream a live video while overlaying it with a graphic. I can create the graphic and save it as a .png file on the tablet. Then,  I need to be able to move and size the graphic to match the cutter live image. If this conversation is best taken off forum, you can reach me at grant4 at wilki dot ca. Thank you very much.

Comment: @gwilki Since 7:13 is the end of the video, I assume you meant [1:45](https://youtu.be/0kYF3fgwhBs?t=105)? However, since you're using WiFi camera, I'd like to know how you can access the feed on Android for now (directly from browser? Exclusive app by them?), or the model of the endoscope, because  how they send the feed data might be [specific and proprietary per model/brand](https://n8henrie.com/2019/02/reverse-engineering-my-wifi-endoscope-part-4/) (or in other words, there might be no generic solution that applicable to any WiFi camera).

Comment: Well, for the generic solution, there *might* be some apps that allow the user to overlay the whole screen on *any* apps and add some images/draw on it, but I haven't done any research on it...

Answer (score 0):

great, I got it . This is easy and possible, SO first of all i need to know the camera you are using to record or live preview your work ?

You need a good high resolution camera , which can zoom at that detail what was shown in your Youtube link . 
Secondly if the camera has live streaming / mirro link options that will be cool , cause you can connect to TV  / Mobile in android and get the camera  live streaming in you mobile or tablet. 
Your tablet with android 6.0 is good enough . 
The important thing is you Camera that will record / live stream when you work.

Secondly , you can do this wirelessly and wired way. 
Wireless ,if you cam has a wifi direct / mirrocast , airplay like features , wired with it supports direct camera raw data to pc streaming ...

Hope this helps..

Comment: Andre: First, I'm sorry about the youtube time. I should have said 3:19. That's where my interest starts. As for the camera, I am using this one: https://www.ebay.com/itm/For-Android-iPhone-WIFI-Endoscope-Waterproof-Borescope-Inspection-Camera-8-LED/282606613184?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&var=581788369393&_trksid=p2060353.m1438.l2649.

Comment: The resolution is very good and its lightweight and small size is ideal for my application. It will live stream while I work. I use it wirelessly. Finally, the app that I am using to stream/record is this one: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cn.com.buildwin.YCamera3. Right now, I stream the camera input onto my tablet. Then, I tape a transparent overlay onto my tablet and trace the cutter with a sharpie. I would like to be able to do the "trace" with an app.

Comment: Andrew: My time comment was directed to you. Sorry again. I am using this setup for turning the inside of things like vases and at 3:19, Alan starts to turn a vase. The cutter disappears into the vase, but since the camera is trained on the cutter, the turner knows where the cutter is relative to the outside of the vase. The overlay feature that I am looking for is used to set a fixed wall thickness. When the overlay "touches" the outside of the live video vase, I stop turning at that spot.